# Como alterar uma célula baseada no valor de outra célula?

Tags: vba

Problema: Importar dados não vem com os zeros a esquerda

Importei dados de um arquivo de texto, porém, mesmo configurando para importar no formato TEXTO, as células de uma coluna que no arquivo era 08 são importadas somente como 8. Como vou usar a função concatenar, preciso que tenha o zero a esquerda.

A melhor solução seria arrumar esse problema na fonte, ou seja, importar os arquivos como foram escritos.

Porém, se não for possível, notei:

- O problema só ocorre quando as células da primeira coluna são "C170"
- Quando uso a função =texto(Y2;"00") conserta o problema do zero a esquerda, mas tenho que criar uma nova coluna com a correção e isso fica fora de mão.

O que eu queria era a maneira mais eficiente (de preferencia sem usar a clipboard ou criar novas colunas!) de adicionar esses zeros a esquerda para usar o concatenar.

Tentei fazer com esse código, mas ele alterou registros que não atendem as condições:

```
 For Each cell In rng.Cells
            If cell.Value = "c170" Then
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 30) = "8" Then
            dd = cell.Offset(0, 30).Value
            With cell.Offset(0, 30)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = "0" & dd
            End With
              End If
```

Comment: Não tenho certeza se eu entendi o problema.. Talvez eu tenha falado besteira na resposta, pode me dizer se é isso que espera ou se não, poderia dar mais detalhes do por quê que não atende?

Comment: Desculpe Math, nunca tinha entrado na plataforma, apanhei um pouco. A fórmula não resolve, pois eu concateno mais de 37 células, e adicionar essa formula em todas fica inviável.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Vou tentar responder apropriadamente.

Comment: Não é só você tirar o `if` da segunda linha? Não entendi o que ele tá fazendo ali.

Comment: Ele aplica a condição só se o valor da célula for "C170"

Comment: realmente, como você disse, o ideal seria corrigir o problema na importação, porem para isso é necessário que você nos mostre como você está fazendo, dei uma resposta usando a função *Format*, veja se te atende

Comment: Por favor faça a postagem da sua planilha.
Estou me sentindo "no escuro" para poder lhe ajudar melhor. Se tiver problemas em fornecer informações da empresa, substitua por valores não condizentes, mas mantenha algo para poder testar se funciona. at.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/gg251755(v=office.15).aspx) da seguinte maneira:

```vb
Dim numeroQualquer As Integer
Dim numeroFormatado As String

numeroQualquer = 8
numeroFormatado = Format(numeroQualquer, "00")
```

O valor da variável `numeroFormatado` seria `08`.

> **Nota:** altere onde está `"00"` para exibir mais ou menos zeros a esquerda.